# IE8 request problems in intranet

Tags: internet-explorer-8, intranet

One of our customers has problems using our CMS (hosted at a server on their intranet). The problem **does only occur in IE8** and not in other Browsers like **FF** or **Safari**.

It looks as if from time to time (at around every 3rd click) **some requests do not complete**.
I think it might be that the **browser tries to load images**(pngs, gifs) **but gets stuck** (the bottom status line of the browser sometimes claims to load images when nothin loads anymore).

Access in that intranet needs **no proxy** (and does not use one, they only use a proxy for external sites).

I have no clue about the reasons. **Does that sound familiar? Any suggestions?**

**EDIT:** Using IE8 over a ssh tunnel did not result in request beeing aborted or unresponsiv! It has to be something in the intranet then.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Fiddler](http:///www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to watch all the HTTP work IE is doing.  This should enable you to track down the requests/responses which are failing, timing out, or otherwise behaving oddly.

It won't fix the issue, but it should help you narrow down what the issue is.

Comment: I know Ethereal. Is Fiddler easier to use or better in result than Ethereal?

Comment: @Tha, shhh, don't let the guys who made it hear you call it Ethereal - it's not been called that for years and they're trying to ditch that name. It's now called [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). And they're much of a muchness, but Fiddler has better HTTP presentation.

Comment: Fiddler is different.  Wireshark (ethereal) is far superior for network traffic monitoring.  Fiddler is going to give you a graphical tree of the HTTP process b/t you and the server, usually providing all the info you need to find the source of web/broswer issue

Comment: thx for the info

Answer (score 1):

Try the iefaq.info fix script. [Website here](http://iefaq.info/index.php?action=artikel&cat=45&id=136). [Script Here](http://iefaq.info/attachments/136/ie8-rereg.all.zip).

It tends to fix a lot of crazy IE8 problems for me.

Comment: the site does not claim that this fixscript will fix any connection/request problems

Comment: Correct. It's still my first stop with crazy IE errors, as it's fixed a multitude of seemingly random quirks. No guarantees, but it's quick and wont break anything.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the images aren't trying to go thru the proxy?

A couple things to try:  If the images don't get loaded, can you right-click and view them?  After viewing all the images, does the page then reload properly?

Can you check the server logs to see if the images are getting requested?

Does your page validate, and if not is IE running in [compatibility mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/introducing-compatibility-view)?

Comment: Well, i am not sure how to chek if the images try to get through the proxy(?), but proxy is deactivated for internal sites in the IE8. 
Problem is that sometimes the page is not getting loaded fully (hangs) an dthe request is being interruptet somehow. No there isn't any Non-image to click on - cause the page load is stopped.

Comment: If you hit stop when the page hangs, is there anything when you "view source"?  Does the request even hit the server?

Comment: Yes the page is loaded partially; page gets rendered using different html-parts.

Comment: Does is stop at the same point consistently?  Are there any img links in the loaded part, and can you load them in IE?

Comment: No, it does stop only sometimes and at different points (approx. each 3rd loading mouse click) and when it does there are no img-links visible to load.

Comment: Very strange - at this point, I think you'll have to try Fiddler.